# Unit testing not making any sense

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I doing some unit tests using Jest for React.

For some reason, when I'm expecting it to not be null, it Received null in the response.

```
describe('Components: FlightSummary', () => {
  it('should render local time by default', () => {
    const { queryByText } = render();

    ['18:10', '18:15', '18:18', '18:23', '18:30', '18:35'].forEach(
      timeValue => {
        expect(queryByText(timeValue)).not.toBeNull();
      }
    );
```

```
expect(received).not.toBeNull()

Received: null

  62 |     ['18:10', '18:15', '18:18', '18:23', '18:30', '18:35'].forEach(
  63 |       timeValue => {
> 64 |         expect(queryByText(timeValue)).not.toBeNull();
     |                                            ^
  65 |       }
  66 |     );
```

And when I change the code to expect null, it Received a value in the response.

```
describe('Components: FlightSummary', () => {
  it('should render local time by default', () => {
    const { queryByText } = render();

    ['18:10', '18:15', '18:18', '18:23', '18:30', '18:35'].forEach(
      timeValue => {
        expect(queryByText(timeValue)).toBeNull();
      }
    );
```

```
expect(received).toBeNull()

Received: <div>18:10</div>

  62 |     ['18:10', '18:15', '18:18', '18:23', '18:30', '18:35'].forEach(
  63 |       timeValue => {
> 64 |         expect(queryByText(timeValue)).toBeNull();
     |                                        ^
  65 |       }
  66 |     );
```

I have no idea what's going on; have never seen this before. ToT

Comment: Based on the results, I'd say `'18:10'` works but one of the other times doesn't. Suggestion - separate them as separate tests. Don't try and be clever with loops, iteration, abstraction, etc., as it makes it harder to see what fails. Unit tests should be the simplest thing ever - if you look at them and wonder why it failed, then it's not a good test, even if it behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea; I tested each of them separately and identify the bug. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In a quite recent version of Jest [`describe.each` and `test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) were added, which will help you with the visibility of what exactly have failed.

You can try this instead:

```
describe('Components: FlightSummary', () => {
  it.each(
    ['18:10', '18:15', '18:18', '18:23', '18:30', '18:35']
  )('should render local time (%s) by default', (timeValue) => {
    const { queryByText } = render();

    expect(queryByText(timeValue)).toBeNull();
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Teneff; I broke it down to test each time and identify the problem. :)